# BSPWM not Working on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window-manager

I am currently running Ubuntu with the default desktop environment (Unity? Gnome? Not sure which one it is anymore) and am trying to install [BSPWM](https://github.com/baskerville/bspwm). I have my bspwmrc in `~/.config/bspwm/`, and my sxhkdrc in `~/.config/sxhkd/`. Both files have execute permissions. I can copy their contents below if you would like.

When I go to the display manager and select BSPWM, it won't start. I tried using Super+Enter to open a terminal, a keybinding which I verified, and nothing happens.

I was able to run sxhkd from my current DE and Super+Enter did open a terminal.

What do I need to do to get this program running?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and fixed it. All you have to do is

- `chmod +x` both `bspwmrc` and `sxhkdrc`.
- Make sure you copied `bspwm.desktop` to the xsessions folder with

  ```
  sudo cp (folder where bspwm is installed)/contrib/freedesktop/bspwm.desktop /usr/share/xsessions/`
  ```

  instead of editing `.xinitrc`.

I know this got posted a long time ago, but I'm mainly writing this for other people that are searching a fix for this issue. Please note that this is intended for Ubuntu Desktop users only.

Comment: Note that the question says that those two files are executable already. Can you expand a little on your second step?

Comment: Instructions for this window manager are terrible. However, I want to give it a try: I have the `bspwm.desktop` in `/usr/share/xsessions/`, but bspwm is not listed among the available sessions in the login screen. Do you know why?